# Firefox local ajax call

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have implemented the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436670/local-html-file-ajax-call-and-jquery-woes), but it is not working in Firefox.

<strike>IE loads and reads the XML document fine</strike> Strike that, if the type of data is "string" the data variable holds the XML, but loading it into the xml variable returns the same function below. The XML file is a flat filed stored in the same folder as the HTML file. The file is being ran from `"file:///D:/..."`, not from a webserver.

**Firefox** version is **16.0.2** and I have tried **jquery 1.7.1 and 1.8.2**. I have done a `dataType` comparison and the data is not `XML`, but just says `Object`.

I did an alert of `$(data).contents` and get:

```
function (c, d) {
    var e = p.map(this, b, c);
    return bc.test(a) || (d = c), d && typeof d == "string" && (e = p.filter(d, e)), e = this.length > 1 && !bg[a] ? p.unique(e) : e, this.length > 1 && bd.test(a) && (e = e.reverse()), this.pushStack(e, a, k.call(arguments).join(","));
}
```

I have tried setting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to **false**, but that has no effect.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "COBIE.xml",
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            if (typeof data == "string") {
                xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xml.async = false;
                xml.loadXML(data);

                // Returned data available in object "xml"
                setMessage("XML date has been loaded");
            } else if (typeof data == "xml") {
                xml = data;
                alert($(xml).contents);
                // Returned data available in object "xml"
                setMessage("XML date has been loaded");
            } else {
                alert($(data).contents);
                setMessage("I have no idea what data you're trying to load");
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            setMessage(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: js is weak-typed language, `typeof data` will only return `'string'` or `'object'` in your case.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a local XAMPP or Node.js server and using that? It takes about an hour the first time to get it running and about 10 minutes forever after; might save you some time and energy mucking with browser security policies, depending on exactly what your end goal is (i.e. for development in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. My XML had some funny stuff in it, so I couldn't get it to parse correctly, but it wasn't giving errors. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed, you can use F12 to view the HTML of the page, as well as have access to a console.

Then, instead of using alert to look at $(data).contents, you can use console.debug like so

```
console.debug($(data).contents);
```

I'm not sure I know the answer to your question, exactly but this should give you a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks. I've added that functionality, but so far I haven't been able to find an error to report.